# How to explain risks of Access 2007 development vs. SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a client who wants to develop an application using Access 2007.  For the stated short term purposes, Access 2007 fits their specification:

- approx 30K master records
- 6 or fewer users
- department file server

The issue is that the client is very technically naive and isn't at all aware of the trouble they might get into if the scope increases.  The application will be storing master data that will be uploaded into an enterprise system and I fear that six months from now I'll be hearing any of the following issues:

- we need to keep all of the historical data (suddenly we have 3M rows)
- we need fine grained and airtight user level security
- we keep getting corrupt data records
- our database wasn't backed up for three months (because a user kept it open)

I've done a few small Access databases but I'm a SQL server dev by trade and I know how to use it to solve most any problem.  I don't know if my client should be worried about their choice of technology - and if they should, I'm not 100% sure how best to communicate the risks to them.

Comment: You could explain the risks you have mentioned and suggest starting with SQL server express, it will certainly fullfill their current needs and removes concerns of cost. Then if needed it'll be a much easier task to move into an enterprise version of SQL server.

Comment: Is the question here whether or not Access is an appropriate front end or whether it's an appropriate data store? Seems to me there's nothing in the "objections" above that apply to anything but the back end.

Comment: It is important to note that you not going to be building  your forms and reports with sql server. So, when you are suggesting to use SQL server, what were/are you planning to use to develop the front end application part with? You would not call VB.net a database system and ask should I use vb.net or sql server? Access is the GUI development tool, and you are free to THEN choose the database engine to use. That database engine can be JET (or the new engine is ACE), or you might be using Oracle or SQL server or MySql.  However, I fail to see how SQL server can replace vb.net or Access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I fear that six months from now I'll be hearing any of the following issues:*

- *we need to keep all of the historical data (suddenly we have 3M
     rows)*

Three million rows isn't necessarily a deal-breaker for a Jet/ACE data store.  Depends on amount of data in each of those rows.

- *we need fine grained and airtight user level security*

This is a compelling reason to move data storage to client-server db.

- *we keep getting corrupt data records*

That should almost never happen with a proper Access implementation, contrary to claims by Access bigots.  It *will* happen if you're running across an unreliable network.  But, if that's your client's situation, you should either fix the network problems or ditch Access for data storage.

- *our database wasn't backed up for three months (because a user kept
     it open)*

You can build on Arvin Meyer's [KickEmOff](http://www.datastrat.com/Code/KickEmOff.txt) approach.  But with <= 6 users currently, it might be easier to deal with the situation without code for now.  Just ask them to close out long enough for the backup.  You could have your automated backup routine create a notice when its attempt fails, so this shouldn't have to be a constant thing.

In any case, suggest you design the current application so that an eventual migration to SQL Server will be less troublesome.  Avoid Access-specific features: hyperlink data type; lookup fields; multi-value fields; attachment fields; and so forth.  Since you're experienced with SQL Server, it should be fairly easy to create a test SQL Server database and link a copy of your Access front-end to it.  Test periodically as you develop the Access front-end.  Then you look like a hero when the client recognizes a need to move the data storage to SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a mixed Sql/Access dev shop and understand your concerns, but the sheer usability of Access often wins out for users. Where we have mission critical data and need to use Access we simply used Linked tables - best of both worlds, Sql handles Security, Backups etc and Access provides the front end.

Answer (score 2):

To me, the obvious answer is to develop an Access front end to an Access back end for the initial implementation, but doing the development with upsizing the back end to SQL Server in mind.

That means just applying commonsense to what you do, as @HansUp suggests (i.e., not using Access-specific functionality), and designing your data retrieval so that it will work well with a server back end.

If, on the other hand, either the increased amount of data or the security issues are actually not just remote possibilities but likely to become issues during the lifetime of the app, I'd go with a SQL Server back end from the beginning. But your description of the situation really doesn't sound like that's the case at all.

Certainly the corruption and backup concerns are completely misplaced. Proper maintenance and backup has to be in place, and the operating environment has to be stable, but all of that applies to any database engine, not just to Jet/ACE.

Comment: @dportas You both need to cool down. If you want to fight over something, do it offsite. David, this is the second time I've warned you about this, and don't even try to play the "it's not me" card. If you *attract* noise, we'll deal with that just a much as if you *generate* noise. Now be civil, *both of you*.

Answer (score 1):

Explain to your client that you will have to charge much more money to create, implement, maintain, repair and later upsize the application. Explain that they will not save money in the long run and that they will be better off if they go ahead and allow you to properly prepare now. That being said, I agree with @HansUp suggestions. You can give the customer what they want and still prepare for the likely eventualities. Think of it as job security.

Answer (score 0):

There are Price and GUI advantages to using Access over SQL that for the non-technical people are really attractive. I think given your scenario then maybe the "customer" is right - aren't they always!

However, your 4 "following issues" really answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

If your user is technically naive then there is not much point in using technical language.  If at all possible when l speak to users the language and terms I used are the same my users understand.  Also compliment your users when possible it makes them feel good and make you look good in their eyes.  Here's some suggested ideas.

Using Access 2007 is an excellent idea, easy to develop with and change to met your needs.  However there are a number of very strong technical reasons for using another free tool, namely SQL express to store the data.

Why use SQL express?

Its free !

Security of the data will be a very high priority (even if client has not mentioned this use this as a reason).  Point out how easy it would be to steal all the data from Access compared to SQL server.  See this book for excellent detail regarding Access security.  The user level security for SQL server is much simpler and easier with SQL server, and will cost less money to implement, as well as being more secure.

Backing up of data.  In order to back up the access database no one can be using the database or even connected to the database.  With SQL server can back it up at any time.  Less down time or in other words greater productivity using this other FREE tool.

Data corruption.  One issue with Access database, is corruption of the database.  What does this mean?  It is possible to lose up to a days worth of work, with SQL server this issue is much very much less likely to occur.  There are even situations where it is not possible to recover the database.  Hence this loss of productivity can be minimised if using SQL server.

When this tool gains greater recognition and other departments wish to use it, as no doubt it will.  Moving to a larger enterprise database system will be much easier and less costly to develop, if you use SQL server express as the data store.

The above are just suggestions, based on the assumption you user is wishing to expend as little money as possible, and the limitations / resources you put in your posting.

I also appreciate that not every one will agree with what l have put in the suggestions above.  They are not meant as detailed technical points, more as suggested ways of persuading a technically naive client to consider using SQL server express as the back end db for an Access db used for a departmental application

Comment: The comment about corruption is vastly overstated. I have had dozens of clients using Jet/ACE back ends for their flagship Access database applications since 1996 and during that time, nobody has lost any significant amount of data (in one case, 3 records were lost, for instance). Losing "days" of work means there are no backups, which is a deployment error, not a flaw in Access.

Comment: HansUp sorry heres the link http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Access-Database-Protection-Security/dp/1590591267

Comment: David-W-Fenton thanks for point out my error, l meant a days worth of work.  Which is my opinion based on my previous experience.

Comment: It's possible to lose huge amounts of data with SQL Server if your backups aren't working properly, so I really don't see the point in singling out Jet/ACE here.